# Label Text middle truncate

Tags: iphone

I have taken a custom tableViewCell with 2 labels .if the text in the second label exceeds i am showing the text in the second label with middle truncation. when the user clicks on the truncated text cell i need to pop up an alert with the complete text . any idea how to find the cell which contains the truncated text .

Answer (score 0):

a lable is truncuated when it's size become greater than fram width. you can find both these by using

lable.frame.size.width

and NSString sizeWithFont method. compare then and found if your size of lable is greater than width. enjoy :)

Comment: I Kept AdjustToFit = NO ; so the font size is not going to change. Thanks for your quick replay.

Comment: and the width of the label also not getting changed

Answer (score 0):

as you uses a custom tableviewcell just give your labels tag values and at the time of cell click just find out both the labels using the tag values and do what you need to do ie show whole text to user in alert view

Comment: i have 10 cells in a table view . i want to show the alert to the user when only the text text truncates. first we need to find out which cell is truncated in the run time